# twitter bootstrap: is form-group class required inside of a form

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

Using Bootstrap, do I need to wrap the "form-group" class around each individual input or can i wrap it around an entire set of inputs (or can I omit it completely as my form has worked with and without it)?

According to the bootstrap docs it seems like it's used simply for formatting purposes ("optimum spacing") and isn't required for properly collecting user input: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Here's what the code looks like if I wrap the form-group class around a series of inputs:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="one" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input One:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="one">
            </div>
            <label for="two" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Input Two:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="two">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'd also like to know if recommended practice suggests using it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great thing about bootstrap is, it's up to you. You are correct in that it is only used for styling purposes. Using the `form-control` class only adds the following styles to the element:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

All it really does is help you get a more standard looking form. My advice would be to use it in a consistent manner, for example, group x elements with a `.form-control` class, or, do them individually, but don't chop and change unless absolutely neccessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm inquiring about the `form-group` class not the `form-control` class. Nevertheless, you've answered my question: these classes are strictly for styling and making the elements look nice